# Can anyone explain the scene from Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix book when Dumbledore hexes the four Ministry workers before escaping?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

Here is the paragraph from the book:

> A streak of silver light flashed around the room; there was a bang like a gunshot and the floor trembled; a hand grabbed the scruff of Harry's neck and forced him down on the floor as a second silver flash went off; several of the portraits yelled, Fawkes screeched and a cloud of dust filled the air. Coughing in the dust, Harry saw a dark figure fall to the ground with a crash in front of him; there was a shriek and a thud and somebody cried, 'No!'; then there was the sound of breaking glass, frantically scuffling footsteps, a groan ... and silence.

**Things I want to know:**

- Things like why there was a thud?
- There were four ministry workers then why Dumbledore only used two spells?
- Why was there *the sound of breaking glass, frantically scuffling footsteps, a groan*?
- I want to know the whole context.

Comment: I expect that the scene was written like that so that you could have fun imagining exactly what happened for yourself.

Comment: _"You may not like it, but you can't deny Dumbledore's got style!"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intent of the scene is to imply how skilled Dumbledore is, without trying to describe the duel in detail - it's bordering on an '[Offscreen Moment of Awesome](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OffscreenMomentOfAwesome)' (warning: TV Tropes link).

The thud is probably either one of the Aurors, or (less likely as it's described in sequence with a shriek) some inaninmate object, being knocked to the floor.

There are at least two spells producing a streak of silver light, which may come from Dumbledore or one of the Aurors; this does not preclude other spells that do not produce that effect, and which Harry may not have been aware of. The described spells may have taken down more than one Auror each, but given that enough are still conscious to (in turn) fall to the ground with a crash, shriek and (probably) collapse with a thud, and cry 'No', it's more likely those were initial clashes in the duel but not responsible for incapacitating more than one person.

Breaking glass, frantically shuffling footsteps, a groan - being described in sequence may imply they relate to the same person - so being hit by (or into/through) glass, trying to get out of being a target but unable to do much more than shuffle, then being hit in a way that produces a groan.

There is a lot of conjecture to this however; all we can say for absolute certain is that all four Aurors (or three Aurors plus Fudge) ended up incapacitated, while Dumbledore appears unscathed.

The narrative technique is to suggest a fairly swift, frantic battle that Dumbledore dominates, without trying to describe every moment in detail. It relies on the imagined fight looking cooler than a detailed description would.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer above did a pretty good job.

I did want to point out that there are only two Aurors - Kingsley and Dawlish. Then there’s Percy, Dolores, and Fudge.

There are two silver flashes but it doesn’t mean Dumbledore only uses two spells. That’s all Harry could see with his head held down. Or, the silver light could’ve been a spell like a part lua, which can be controlled to hit multiple targets, hence, it streaks.

The loud bang is probably one of the Ministry workers’ spells. The “No!” is most likely Fudge or Umbridge realising Dumbledore is winning the fight.